# Django1.6 migrates with South

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.6 in a project, I'd like to add a column "number" in my table(model) "Tag". After having added this column in model.py, I run the command:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

But I've got an error when I enter in the table "Tag" in the backend : "number: no such column". It seems that the migrate didn't worked.

How can I do with that? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your model. Did you have any migrations files before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

will only create a migration file for your model change. You'll need to run

```
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

to apply the migration

Comment: Thanks, but before I modifier the model.py, do I have to run "python manage.py migrate myapp --fake" ?

Comment: It depends on the current state of migrations of your app. If it is not the first time you used migrations in your application, you don't need faking. But if it is the first time you use it, you need to: 1. Convert app to south. 2. Create a migration for new field. 3. Fake initial migration (http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app) 4. Run your field migration

Comment: what does it means using --fake?

Comment: South uses special db table to store data about what migrations were applied and what weren't. Sometimes you will face a situation, when some changes in database were made before you generated a migration for that changes (i.e. when you didn't use migrations in your app before). In that situation you will use --fake to tell south that migration is in fact applied and south does not need to apply it again. It needs only to mark migration as applied

Comment: I've run `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial` and `python manage.py migrate` before, so I don't have to use fake?

Comment: No, you don't need to use --fake in this case

Answer (score 1):

With that command you are just creating the migration. You still have to run:

`./manage.py migrate appname`

in order to apply the migration.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto` will create the migration, now you need to apply it, see [Changing the model](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model).